# Gallery, sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite, gallery

I am now stuck at a point and can't find any solution.

Description : I have a sqlite database having a table(channel table) which have 4 column

```
 uid      channel_name     cid(country id)      rating
```

uid is Unique channel id.

I have three images with star rating if star is yellow then channel have either 4 or 5 rating 
if star is half yellow then channel rating is 2 or 3. if star is white then rating 1 will be considered.

I am showing these three images from gallery widgets in android. ant the channel name below star images. according to channel rating.

```
 public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
            View view = null;
            Cursor mCursor=db.dataChannelsName();
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            String [] channels_name = new String[mCursor.getCount()];
            for(int icount=0; icount<mCursor.getCount();icount++) { 
                channels_name[icount] =  mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                mCursor.moveToNext();
            }

            if(paramView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items1, null);
                    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
                    TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);

                    image1.setImageResource(mImageIds[paramInt]);
                    description.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
                    description.setText(channels_name[paramInt]);
            } else {
                    view = paramView;
            }

            return view;
```

Question 1:

How will i show only these three images for all channel with different channels name.?

Question 2:

It can be possible to have same name channel in database

I am using sql queries and cursor for retrieving data.

Now my problem is when user will select the particular channel from the gallery then there is a possibility that there can be more than one channel with same name.

I just want to store the uid when user click on the channel name from the gallery??

**EDIT**  I just solved the second question but i am stuck at question 1

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets begin fixing some things, shall we?

```
public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
   View view = null;
   Cursor mCursor=db.dataChannelsName();
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
   String [] channels_name = new String[mCursor.getCount()];
   for(int icount=0; icount<mCursor.getCount();icount++) { 
       channels_name[icount] =  mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
       mCursor.moveToNext();
   }
```

Now the getView Function is called everytime a listView displays a new Row (even when scrolling!!)...I'm assuming `db.dataChannelName()` fires a query `SELECT * from channel` (or worse, you might be opening and closing the database)....This is a very expensive operation, you should query it once in the constructor, store the array of channel names as a member variable and use it for the rest of the adapter.

Here's a concise way..

```
public View getView(int paramInt, View view, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
    if(view== null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items1, null);
        } 

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);

        image1.setImageResource(mImageIds[paramInt]); // i'm assuming 0 - 0 star, 1 - 1 star, etc...
        description.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
        description.setText(channels_name[paramInt]); //remember channel_name was obtained in the constructor.


return view
}
```

Comment: you are right. getView method will be called every time. By the way i canceled this design and using different design for app and thanks for your time.